# Php5-fpm Crash if much visitors

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

I decided to change my OP to Nginx from Litespeed because i read much about the low resource that Nginx would cost.

Im running a Wordpress site with 500 users online

Okay thanks Guys for that much help :) I edited some things.

I have some questions left too:

Do i have to remove the ; before the pm. settings? I removed it What config counts? I got two fast cgi one in /etc/php5/fpm called php-fpm.conf and one in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d called www.conf ?

I tried the new config over night and when i wake up i already got a blank page. Top:

```
top - 13:55:27 up 1 day, 19:28,  2 users,  load average: 0.18, 0.36, 0.19
Tasks:  84 total,   1 running,  83 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3974264k total,  1051360k used,  2922904k free,   162380k buffers
Swap:  3998700k total,        0k used,  3998700k free,   609220k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 1857 www-data  20   0  193m  55m  22m S    0  1.4   0:04.67 php5-fpm
    1 root      20   0  8356  808  680 S    0  0.0   0:01.37 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
```

I think cpu usage is now lower, but thats not fixing the crash...

My configs are now: php-fpm.conf

```
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; FPM Configuration ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; All relative paths in this configuration file are relative to PHP's install
; prefix (/usr). This prefix can be dynamicaly changed by using the
; '-p' argument from the command line.

; Include one or more files. If glob(3) exists, it is used to include a bunch of
; files from a glob(3) pattern. This directive can be used everywhere in the
; file.
; Relative path can also be used. They will be prefixed by:
;  - the global prefix if it's been set (-p arguement)
;  - /usr otherwise
;include=/etc/php5/fpm/*.conf

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Global Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[global]
; Pid file
; Note: the default prefix is /var
; Default Value: none
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid

; Error log file
; If it's set to "syslog", log is sent to syslogd instead of being written
; in a local file.
; Note: the default prefix is /var
; Default Value: log/php-fpm.log
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log

; syslog_facility is used to specify what type of program is logging the
; message. This lets syslogd specify that messages from different facilities
; will be handled differently.
; See syslog(3) for possible values (ex daemon equiv LOG_DAEMON)
; Default Value: daemon
;syslog.facility = daemon

; syslog_ident is prepended to every message. If you have multiple FPM
; instances running on the same server, you can change the default value
; which must suit common needs.
; Default Value: php-fpm
;syslog.ident = php-fpm

; Log level
; Possible Values: alert, error, warning, notice, debug
; Default Value: notice
;log_level = notice

; If this number of child processes exit with SIGSEGV or SIGBUS within the time
; interval set by emergency_restart_interval then FPM will restart. A value
; of '0' means 'Off'.
; Default Value: 0
emergency_restart_threshold = 1

; Interval of time used by emergency_restart_interval to determine when 
; a graceful restart will be initiated.  This can be useful to work around
; accidental corruptions in an accelerator's shared memory.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
emergency_restart_interval = 1s

; Time limit for child processes to wait for a reaction on signals from master.
; Available units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
process_control_timeout = 10s

; The maximum number of processes FPM will fork. This has been design to control
; the global number of processes when using dynamic PM within a lot of pools.
; Use it with caution.
; Note: A value of 0 indicates no limit
; Default Value: 0
process.max = 150

; Send FPM to background. Set to 'no' to keep FPM in foreground for debugging.
; Default Value: yes
;daemonize = yes

; Set open file descriptor rlimit for the master process.
; Default Value: system defined value
rlimit_files = 1024

; Set max core size rlimit for the master process.
; Possible Values: 'unlimited' or an integer greater or equal to 0
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_core = 0

; Specify the event mechanism FPM will use. The following is available:
; - select     (any POSIX os)
; - poll       (any POSIX os)
; - epoll      (linux >= 2.5.44)
; - kqueue     (FreeBSD >= 4.1, OpenBSD >= 2.9, NetBSD >= 2.0)
; - /dev/poll  (Solaris >= 7)
; - port       (Solaris >= 10)
; Default Value: not set (auto detection)
; events.mechanism = epoll

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Pool Definitions ; 
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Multiple pools of child processes may be started with different listening
; ports and different management options.  The name of the pool will be
; used in logs and stats. There is no limitation on the number of pools which
; FPM can handle. Your system will tell you anyway :)

; To configure the pools it is recommended to have one .conf file per
; pool in the following directory:
include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf

request_terminate_timeout = 30s

pm.max_children = 25

; The number of child processes created on startup.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Default Value: min_spare_servers + (max_spare_servers - min_spare_servers) / 2
pm.start_servers = 5

; The desired minimum number of idle server processes.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
pm.min_spare_servers = 2

; The desired maximum number of idle server processes.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
pm.max_spare_servers = 5

; The number of seconds after which an idle process will be killed.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'ondemand'
; Default Value: 10s
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
```

fastcgi_params:

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;

#fastcgi_param  HTTPS           $https;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;

fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```

nginx config:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 500;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 40;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    # access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    # error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

 gzip_vary on;
 gzip_proxied any;
 gzip_comp_level 9;
 gzip_buffers 16 8k;
 gzip_http_version 1.1;
 gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/$
```

www.conf

```
; Start a new pool named 'www'.
; the variable $pool can we used in any directive and will be replaced by the
; pool name ('www' here)
[www]

user = www-data
group = www-data


pm = dynamic

pm.max_children = 25

pm.start_servers = 5

pm.min_spare_servers = 2

pm.max_spare_servers = 5

pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;

pm.max_requests = 100

request_terminate_timeout = 120s
```

The Mashine:
Dualcore 
4gb ram

Comment: What does the PHP-FPM error log say?

Comment: Theres only the record about when i restart the fpm some other...[04-Apr-2012 13:46:44] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[04-Apr-2012 13:46:44] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[04-Apr-2012 13:46:44] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1744
[04-Apr-2012 13:46:44] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[04-Apr-2012 13:48:57] NOTICE: [pool www] child 1748 exited with code 0 after 132.647614 seconds from start
[04-Apr-2012 13:48:57] NOTICE: [pool www] child 1829 started

Comment: I just noticed that php fpm crashes faster if i disable/enable or edit my wordpress files. But im not 100% sure...

Comment: Are you still getting the crashes? Did you checked usage of `APC`? Usually you define a pool in a separate config file (where all your pm settings go).

Comment: Yes it still crashes. The crashes seems to increase with more visitors on my page. I dont see the apc prozess in "top". How can i check it? I used cron to restart php fpm every 2 minutes for now.... I realy need to fix that problem soon!

Comment: So nobody has any ideas? I already disabled the most plugin this ist left: Capability Manager
Category Images II
Category Tags
HeadSpace2
More Fields
Multi Column Category List
PHPFreeChat
Post Tabs
ProPlayer
Sort Query Posts
Taxonomy Images
W3 Total Cache
WP-Mail-SMTP
WP-PageNavi
WP-ReportPost
WP Paging

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not clear whether you are using any opcode cacher like `APC`. First of all, make it enabled. Adjust its the memory to avoid fragmentation. Also, use socket, not http connection from `nginx` to `php5-fpm`, and place that socket on `/dev/shm`. 
In nginx, use `fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php5-fpm.sock;`, and change php5-fpm's config accordingly.

Try to lower `pm.max_children` to something more realistic like 30-40-50-60 and see the load and free memory with `free -m`. See if clients getting any 502/504 errors. Lower `pm.start_servers`, min and max_spare accordingly (15, 5, 25).

If there is a lot of anonymous users, consider to use any caching plugin for wordpress like `WP-FFPC`, `WP Super Cache` or similar.

Disable gzipping if you have it enabled in nginx.

Perhaps you need to adjust `fastcgi_buffer_size` and `fastcgi_buffers` options in nginx.

Check if you have Query cache enabled and sufficient on Mysql.

Have monitoring system like `munin` installed on the site in order to check load/memory consumption/latency etc.

Comment: The connection between nginx and php5-fpm may not be HTTP but just TCP. JFYI.

Answer (score 4):

Your server is likely to suffers when it rans out of memory to run php processes. Your php5-fpm settings seem to be too generous for 4GB RAM. I've had lots of fiddling to arrive at optimal php5-fpm configs (for 32GB ram and +1K online users, here are my relevant params:

```
pm.max_children = 25
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 2 
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_requests = 100
```

Also don't forget to set a request termination timeout to avoid memory shortage due to idle processes:

```
request_terminate_timeout = 120s
```

Whatever timout you use in the above directie should be in accordance with max_execution_time directive in your php.ini.

As for nginx,having gzip  on is a very good idea: It is very cheap CPU-wise and saves your server loads of bandwidth.

```
   #sendfile on;
    #tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/$
```

Good luck

Comment: I tried your config over night, the cpu seems usage seems to be lower now hovewer that didnt fixed the blank pages and the crashes. Heres a Ip counter Image: http://www.abload.de/img/unbenanntsgyxi.png

Comment: I agree with the recommendation to set `request_terminate_timeout`, but your reason is not correct ;) This directive is to kill a running process after a certain amount of CPU time, as a safeguard when PHP's `max_execution_time` could not (which should have a bit smaller value to get the first chance) [[source](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#request-terminate-timeout)].

"To avoid memory shortage due to idle processes", the directive to use is `pm.process_idle_timeout = 40` [[see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20928919/1270008)].

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use pm = ondemand, and make sure the size of the memory_limit in php is sizable to the memory of the machine.

For a 4GB machine with 128 MB in PHP process that would be around ~ 24 PHP-FPM servers you can have running, ondemand is nice as the server would determine that maximum amount of servers and create new as the load goes up.

Comment: Agree that the PHP-FPM ondemand process manager is the better choice in most cases. But its max. number of child processes cannot be calculated like this: `memory_limit` is the absolute max that a PHP process may consume before forcefully terminated. On average, they consume much less.

Comment: *And anyway*, memory is usually not the limiting factor for max. children, rather CPU cores. Max. child count should be set to approx. CPU core count, plus a few to compensate for IO waits etc.. Nothing goes faster beyond 100% CPU load, it's just a difference between waiting in queue and slow parallel serving with switching.